# How expensive is git checkout compared to other version control systems?

Tags: git

I'm not entirely sure how git implements checking out, but presumably it's deleting files on-disk (corresponding to the working copy), and writing files to the working copy from it's internal representation. So it seems to me that if you have a project with a lot of files, git checkout ought to be an expensive thing to do, in terms of disk I/O. But it doesn't seem to take that long usually (although maybe I'm just working with repositories small enough for it not to matter). So is git doing this in a more intelligent way than I would've thought, or is there some other consideration going on here, or is it in fact the case that git checkout is expensive and I'm just not noticing because I have good enough hardware?

Comment: Is your theory that git will waste effort on rewriting even files that haven't changed? Do you have any evidence for that? And why do you think git in particular would be stupider than other VCSes? Nothing in your explanation seems to be specific to it.

Comment: Wouldn't every VCS have to perform the same amount of file IO to modify the same files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are completely swapping between two almost completely different aspects of your project, so that the commonality is minimal, and the differences extensive, then both git and other VCS systems will need to delete and replace a whole load of data. At that point it is implementation efficiency that matters, and even there, git usually has advantages in that it has a fully *local* copy of your files, rather than having to endure network delays between you and the distant network repo.

If you are simply swapping between branches within rather similar versions of the project, you have a lot of pre-existing commonality, and git know this, so doesn't need to do anything for those files. All it needs to do is a little bit of file restoration and you're done.

Plus git is generally optimised for speed. The git@vger.kernel.org thread often has speed optimisations and speed comparisons, so it is important, which isn't always the case with some other systems - having a local repo is key!

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of apples and oranges.  `git checkout` has more in common with to `svn revert` than `svn checkout`, for instance.

`git checkout` works on the local file system only. `git push`, `git pull` are used to synch with a remote repository, and `git clone` is use to download a remote repository.

The actual `git checkout` compares your working folder with the local repository, and updates the files to the repository's version. All locally done, and carries roughly the same amount of overhead as 'git status' or 'svn status'.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Doug Kress says, `git checkout` is local to your box. The performance is only based on IO performance and the efficiency of your file system. So the real consideration is if you have an inefficient file system or bad IO performance.

From the `git update-index` manual:

> Many operations in git depend on your filesystem to have an efficient
>   lstat(2) implementation, so that st_mtime information for working tree
>   files can be cheaply checked to see if the file contents have changed
>   from the version recorded in the index file. Unfortunately, some
>   filesystems have inefficient lstat(2). If your filesystem is one of
>   them, you can set "assume unchanged" bit to paths you have not changed
>   to cause git not to do this check.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html